# Full join multiple queries

Tags: data-analysis

I am trying to full join several queries, two will full join, the other won't. It gives error of

> invalid use of on clause

Is there a comma or semicolon to be used when trying to full join queries?

```
select * from
(query1) query1
full join (query2) query2 
on query1.x = query2.x;   does not join thereafter 
full join (query3) query3 
on query1.x = query3.x;
```

Comment: Remove the first `;` - the `;` denotes the **end** of a SQL statement

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured that is so, though my join did not work because the column attributes were different, I mean query1.x had to be of same data type as query2.x once i got that everything joined nicely.